# The text in the bottom center in the cell and the image in the top center in the same cell

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I want to arrange the image and text in the same cell, image on top and text on bottom.
I tried to add p vertical-align: bottom; but it doesn't work.

I am asking for help, does anyone have any idea how to do it?

My code:

```css
table {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid;
}

img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.top { vertical-align: top; }


p{
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="top">
            <img src='https://dummyimage.com/100' />
            <p>text</p>
        </td>
         <td class="top">
            <img src='https://dummyimage.com/100' />
            <p>text</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="top">
            <img src='https://dummyimage.com/100' />
            <p>text</p>
        </td>
         <td class="top">
            <img src='https://dummyimage.com/100' />
            <p>text</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: don't use table to present layout. Think about Flexbox

Comment: I use flexbox but still don't know how to put the text on bottom. 

http://jsfiddle.net/Magico_pl/91muqjo6/61/

Comment: something like this? [http://jsfiddle.net/6y59earm/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/6y59earm/1/)

Comment: You want to make the text inside image in bottom ? or beside it

Comment: Done here is an example.
http://jsfiddle.net/Magico_pl/xgdq4kbm/30/